# C++ Application Hang Lottery

Tags: c++, windows

I'm running into an issue with a program I'm trying to write for my C++ class and am looking for help.  The program is supposed to simulate the California super lotto, but is incomplete as I'm trying to solve the problem I'm currently stuck with.  My problem is that I have a section of my program that is causing the application to hang and not continue further, and I can't figure out why.  This is heavily commented with what things are supposed to do.  Could you guys help?

The application hangs on code line 151, and starts with this:  for (int d = 0; d < totalTickets; d++)

Because this is technically homework, I'm not looking for the answer to be given to me, but a push in the right direction.  Thanks in advance for any help you're all able to give me!  The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

// Define functions to be seen by main
int lottoPlayedHere();

// Main function
int main()
{
    lottoPlayedHere();
}

// Generates the tickets for the game and compares all values.
int lottoPlayedHere()
{
    unsigned int randSeed = time(0);
    int difference, randomValue, lowerLimit, upperLimit;
    int winningTicket[6];

    // Ask user for lower and upper limits to the tickets generated
    cout << "Hello.  Please enter the lower limit for the number of tickets to" << endl;
    cout << "generate for this week's super lotto plus." << endl << endl;
    cin >> lowerLimit;

    cout << endl << "Please enter the upper limit for the number of tickets to generate." << endl << endl;
    cin >> upperLimit;

    // Seed the RNG
    srand(randSeed);

    // Do math to determine how many tickets to pull
    difference = upperLimit - lowerLimit;
    randomValue = rand() % difference;
    randomValue += lowerLimit;

    // Fill winningTicket with values
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        winningTicket[i] = 1 + rand() % 47;

        if (i == 5)
        {
            winningTicket[5] = 1 + rand() % 27;
        }
    }

    // This is here to force two elements to be equal so that the program will close 
    // if there is a duplicate value on the lotto ticket in the first five positions.
    // winningTicket[0] = winningTicket[1];

    // DEBUGGING PURPOSES; 
    /* cout << lowerLimit << " " << upperLimit << " " << difference << " " << randomValue << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        cout << winningTicket[j] << endl;
    } */


    // Cleaner code than below, more lines
    for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 5; b++)
        {
            if (a != b)
            {
                if (winningTicket[a] == winningTicket[b])
                {
                    cout << endl << "The winning ticket includes duplicate values across the first five elements.\nThe program will now close." << endl;
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Long code, less lines
    /* if (winningTicket[0] == winningTicket[1] || winningTicket[0] == winningTicket[2] || winningTicket[0] == winningTicket[3] || winningTicket[0] == winningTicket[4] ||
    winningTicket[1] == winningTicket[2] || winningTicket[1] == winningTicket[3] || winningTicket[1] == winningTicket[4] || winningTicket[2] == winningTicket[3] ||
    winningTicket[2] == winningTicket[4] || winningTicket[3] == winningTicket[4])
    {
        cout << "The winning ticket includes duplicate values across the first five elements.\nThe program will now close." << endl;
        exit(0);
    } */

    // Variables for pulled tickets
    int totalTickets = randomValue, counter, mega = 0, oneMega = 0, twoMega = 0, three = 0, threeMega = 0, four = 0, fourMega = 0, five = 0, fiveMega = 0;
    bool megaValue;
    int pulledTicket[6];

    cout  << endl << "The program will now pull the tickets for this week's superlotto." << endl;

    // Pulls tickets depending on min/max values given.  This is where the application hangs.
    for (int d = 0; d < totalTickets; d++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j = 6; j++)
        {
            pulledTicket[j] = 1 + rand() % 47;

            if (j == 5)
            {
                pulledTicket[5] = 1 + rand() % 27;
            }
        }

        // Makes sure the pulled ticket doesn't have duplicate values.  Because I'm pulling so many,
        // this probably isn't needed and should be a break rather than an exit.
        // Perhaps I need to make the pulledTicket loop it's own function?
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++)
            {
                if (pulledTicket[k] == pulledTicket[l])
                {
                    cout << endl << "The pulled ticket includes duplicate values across the first five elements.\nThe program will now close." << endl;
                    // exit(0);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Compares winningTicket to pulledTicket
        for (int c = 0; c < 6; c++)
        {
            counter = 0;
            if (winningTicket[c] == pulledTicket[c])
            {
                counter++;

                // If mega number is equal to pulled ticket, set megaValue to true and increment.
                if (winningTicket[5] == pulledTicket[5])
                {
                    megaValue = true;
                }
            }
        }

        // Categorize the values.
        if (counter == 0 && megaValue == true)
        {
            mega++;
        }
        if (counter == 1 && megaValue == true)
        {
            oneMega++;
        }
        if (counter == 2 && megaValue == true)
        {
            twoMega++;
        }
        if (counter == 3 && megaValue == false)
        {
            three++;
        }
        if (counter == 3 && megaValue == true)
        {
            threeMega++;
        }
        if (counter == 4 && megaValue == false)
        {
            four++;
        }
        if (counter == 4 && megaValue == true)
        {
            fourMega++;
        }
        if (counter == 5 && megaValue == false)
        {
            five++;
        }
        if (counter == 5 && megaValue == true)
        {
            fiveMega++;
        }
    }

    // Print out the winning ticket.
    cout << winningTicket << endl;

    return randomValue;
}
```

Comment: Bloody hell I am an idiot.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error at the exit condition of a loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j = 6; j++)
```

This will never exit; it should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that I overlooked that.  Thank you Fabio.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is right here:

```
for (int j = 0; j = 6; j++)
```

That's going to be an infinite loop, over here.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that I overlooked that.  Thank you Sam.